# Create Apache Alias in 2.4.7

Tags: web, apache2, virtual, hosts, observium

My server ip is internal (I dont have to publish it on internet) 192.168.251.4

I have a site in /opt/observium/html/ folder, I want to reach the site writing http://192.168.251.4/observium in browser.

I tried with virtual hosts without success.

OS: Ubuntu server 14.04LTS
Apache versione: 2.4.7

Thank you!

Comment: I'm trying same approach. but its not working for me. Did you find solution for this ?. Please share if so.

Answer (score 2):

Following covener answer I have too used the "Alias" Feature in apache but you also need to do another piece for the observium to make it work:

In Apache (based on ubuntu) I've added the file `/etc/apache2/conf-available/observium.conf`:

```
<IfModule mod_alias.c>
    Alias /observium /opt/observium/html/
</IfModule>
<Directory /opt/observium/html/>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    <FilesMatch \.php$>
      SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
    </FilesMatch>
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Then activated the configuration (again this refers to ubuntu in RH variant it will be slightly different):

```
a2enconf observium
systemctl reload apache2
```

This will not work yet due to the fact that the observium expect to use the `/` of the site as reference and you need to update that in `/opt/observium/config.php` and add the folowing line:

```
$config['base_url'] = "http://" . $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] . ":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] . "/observium/";
```

(Please note the trailing `/`)

Update: The process above missing one last change:
(Source: http://www.foobar.org/~nick/OBSERVIUM-11.html)
Edit the file `/opt/observium/html/includes/functions.inc.php` and change the following line:

```
$segments = explode('/', trim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/'));
to:
$segments = explode('/', trim($_SERVER['PATH_INFO'], '/'));
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a little odd that in the title you knew it was an "alias" but you didn't mention using the Alias directive.

Should be as simple as

```
Alias /observium  /opt/observium/html
<Directory  /opt/observium/html/>
  Require all granted
</Directory>
```